# Comparing Generics

Tags: java, generics

Hi I'm trying to compare two objects using by extending the generics with the interface Comparable:

```
public class Tree<K extends Comparable<K>>
{
    Node<K> treeNode;

    // Some initialization stuff

    public void test(Node<K> node)
    {
         // Some code

         // This line fails
         if(node.getKey() > treeNode.getKey())
         { ... }

         // Rest of the code
    }
}

public interface Node<K extends Comparable<K>>
{
    // Some code
    public K getNode();

    // Some more code
}
```

But some reason, the compare operator is not recognized. I thought that by extending comparable I could begin using such an operator. What am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Comparable` doesn't let you use `<` or `>` to compare, just like `List` and `Map` don't let you use `[]` for item access. You need to call the [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method, which will indicate the result of the comparison by returning an integer less than, greater than, or equal to 0.

Answer (score 3):

There is no operator overloading in Java. Therefore, you can't use `>` even if the objects implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). You have to use [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) instead.